# Rails: как получить все записи?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте!

Предположим у меня есть контроллер сообщений - Messages, есть соответствующая модель Message.

Миграция:

```
def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.integer :from
      t.integer :to
      t.text    :text
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

Предположим,что мне нужно получить все записи, где соблюдаются два условия:

> 1. from: 1, to: 2
> 2. from: 2, to: 1

т.е. все сообщения между 1 и 2.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, быть может есть какое-нибудь красивое решение?

Спасибо!

Comment: [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or)?

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Message.where(from: 1, to: 2) + Message.where(from: 2, to: 1)
```